# How can one clean the data written before in the form?

Tags: python, forms, web.py

I am currently trying out python's web.py module by making a small form. I wrote one, and received input from the user and wrote them to a (mysql) database table. Every thing is fine, except for one issue. When I run the program and write something in one of the form's fields, it persists to the next time I want to write in that field. How can I reset the field after receiving the data?

this is my code:

```
import web
import MySQLdb
url=('/search', 'search_by_name')
db=web.database(dbn='mysql' ,db='std',user='root', pw='123456')
tmpl=web.template.render('templates/')

class search_by_name:
   form=web.form.Form(
                      web.form.Textbox('username',vpass,web.form.notnull),
                      web.form.Button('search')
                      )
    def GET(self):
        return tmpl.page( self.form) 

    def POST(self):
        form=self.form
        if not form.validates():
            return tmpl.page(form)
        else:
            name=form['username'].value
            a=db.select('student',  where="name=$name", vars=locals())
            row=list(a)
            if row:
                col=row[0]
                return tmpl.table(row,col)
            else:
                return tmpl.message("There isn't student with this name in list")

app=web.application (url,globals())
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: don't worry ;) ill edit it for you so no downvotes

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_form_autocomplete did you try this?? are u looking out for some thing similar

Comment: it would be very helpful if we could see your code